# SQL Server Management Studio, no New Project option

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2008

I used to organize my queries in a `Projects/Solutions` in Management Studio at work. But after I had installed SSMS at home I coulnd't find and option to create new project. In File-> New there is only New Query, and Policy but no Project/Solution.

I do not also have SolutionExplorer `View` tab. I have the newest 64-bit version from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b). Do I have install another version or change some settings?

Comment: I have the same situation. At home I have a 32-bit version of SSMS 2008 with New Project menu, but on the job where installed new 64-bit version of SSMS, Project menu is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Re-run the installer and choose the full install option.